# OpenProcess returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED for 32bit elevated processes

Tags: c, winapi, process

I am looking for a specific eleveated 32bit process on a machine which I would like to terminate. First, I need to be sure it is the right file that is executed.

For that purpose I follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-modules-for-a-process) example by Microsoft of how to get all processes file names using *OpenProcess()*, *EnumProcessModules()*, and *GetModuleFileNameEx()* kernel functions.

When executing from Visual Studio and from an elevated Powershell (x86 or x64) I get an *OpenProcess()* return code of 299, but the process handle is ok and I can get the file name.

When I run the same binary in an elevated CMD shell (tested on Win10 x64 and Win7 x86) then *OpenProcess()* return 5 meaning ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. -- This is a problem to me because for specific reasons the tool will eventually run from CMD.

I have already tried to tweak the desired flags for *OpenProcess()*, but both versions give the same result as described above.

- PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_TERMINATE
- PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_TERMINATE

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess, FALSE, processID);
EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded);
GetModuleFileNameEx(....);
```

Thanks in advance for any hints and pointers!

Comment: If OpenProcess() returns 0 then it failed & GetLastError() will tell you why, is that what your checking?

Comment: OpenProcess returns a process handle. If it fails it returns NULL. Otherwise it returns a valid handle. If it returns a valid handle, do not call GetLastError, the result is meaningless. So the 299 error code means nothing.

Comment: However, what makes you think you can obtain a handle to an elevated process from a non elevated process? The system says access denied for a reason, no?

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to list all privileges held by your process. Compare the list when run under a debugger to the list when run from the command line.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the OP's code is not running from an unelevated process. It is running from an elevated Powershell

Comment: Thank you for your responses! My apologies for the possibly fuzzy description.
@alexk. yes, I use the return value as the handle, and I check the GetLastError(). David, thanks for the hint, I was not aware that the error is not reset in success cases. However, the process is elevated, I see that in the task manager. What is still entirely unclear to me is in what way the execution differs between CMD and PS, both elevated. Are there specific properties I should look out for?

Comment: The initial difference lies in the fact that PowerShell leverages the use of what is known as cmdlets. Later,Windows PowerShell ships with Windows PowerShell ISE which makes it a great scripting environment, which can be used to create and manage different PowerShell scripts that use the .ps1 extension.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't reproduce your error. I tried the method you mentioned on my computer and found no error. If you can, please attach some necessary program screenshots or run-time screenshots. You can also record your operation with GifToScreen tool.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT We know what PowerShell is. The question was more about why an executable behaves differently when started from a cmd process than from a PowerShell process.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for reminding me that I tried OP's method and failed to reproduce his problem. I'm still researching it.

Answer (score -1):

Eventually, I gave up on this in C and implemented it in C# using the *System.Diagnostics.Process* methods without a flaw.

Thanks anyway for all your efforts!